# How to stop cron job email notification

Tags: php, cron

I have hostgator hosting. I want to use Cron Job. I am using this command to perform my task

```
/opt/php54/bin/php /home/abskillz/public_html/cron.php
```

Now the question is every time when cron is perform I got email that your action has processed or etc. Can anyone tell me that how can I stop getting this email?

Comment: Does you written any type of code to send email ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100722/how-do-i-completely-silence-a-cronjob-to-dev-null

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Will that prevent `mail()`/`file_put_contents` functions too?

Comment: Nope it won't. It will just stop the cron job from sending its notification and also from showing you any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remove the output message from my PHP page. So no more emails now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always set some persistent flag to indicate if sending email is required.

```
if (file_exist(__DIR__.'/cron_flag_'.self::SEND_EMAILS.'.php')) {
    mail('a@b.com', 'subject', 'message');
}

if ($this->db->queryScalar('SELECT value FROM cron_flags WHERE type = "'.self::SEND_EMAILS.'"')) {
    mail('a@b.com', 'subject', 'message');
}
```

So if flag is not set, CronJob just will just jump to the end of file and no processing will be done.